# What's wrong with this Ruby dependency?

Tags: ruby, swagger

I am trying to use [source2swagger](https://github.com/solso/source2swagger) on OSX 10.7.5

It depends on "json" so I am installing that, then trying to run as below.

```
machine:source2swagger jpbeuc1$ sudo gem install json
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed json-1.7.7
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for json-1.7.7...
Installing RDoc documentation for json-1.7.7...
machine:source2swagger jpbeuc1$ bin/source2swagger 
bin/source2swagger:4:in `require': no such file to load -- json (LoadError)
    from bin/source2swagger:4
```

Can anyone tell me what's not working here and how to make source2swagger see "json"?

Comment: Try `gem install json` don't use `sudo`

Comment: machine:source2swagger jpbeuc1$ gem install json
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.

Comment: Whats your gem path? do `echo $GEM_PATH`

Comment: I think you have `source2swagger` access to user level and `gems` are in root level. So `source2swagger` not able to find your `json` gem. So install gems in `home`

Comment: do u have `rvm` installed on ur system?

Comment: -bash: rvm: command not found

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25295/discussion-between-codeit-and-joe-beuckman)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `source2swagger` installed in your `local` and `gems` are installed in `root`. So your `source2swagger` which needs `json` can't access those gem which are installed in `root`. So I recommend to gems in `local` always and avoid using `sudo` for installing gems. To manage gems in local I suggest to use [RVM](https://rvm.io/).

Comment: advised that I install rvm - and source2swagger worked after it was installed.